# Yoast SEO/Facebook OG: Image not displaying after fb url change

Tags: wordpress, image, facebook, facebook-opengraph, yoast

I set up my blog to connect to a facebook page, and automatically post articles to it. I set up Yoast SEO and everything worked fine. Then, I changed the name of my Facebook page (I regret this), and it all stopped working. So then I changed the Facebook name back to the original. Now, my articles post to the page as before except that the cover image does not post.

I have googled a lot and also looked through all the stackoverflow responses that I could find that were relevant but I can't find the answer. I am not a website expert, just trying to figure it out on my own.

When I use FB's debugger, it gives me this error:

1 of 1 "Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."

And then at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ it gives me these errors:

1 of 4 "SSL Error   Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid."

2 of 4 "Missing Required Property   The 'og:type' property is required, but not present."

3 of 4 "Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."

4 of 4 "Share App ID Missing    The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog."

When I look at the source for one of my pages, I see all the meta tags, so I don't know why it's having this problem: view-source:https://www.erichalpenny.com/story-steinbeck-eden/

Also, older posts that were right before are no longer right. I am very sure it's because of the change and then change back on the FB page, but I don't know how to just start everything over again. I tried disabling the social Yoast SEO setting and re-enabling but that didn't fix anything.

The SSL error has me concerned, but I don't understand SSL enough to know what that means, and I haven't done anything different with my site, only with the Facebook page.

Also, I have read several things that say there has to be some kind of check of the  file, but I don't know how to do this. I use BlueHost for my wordpress install management.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Eric

Comment: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.erichalpenny.com Your certificate chain is incomplete. (Plus, your certificate will expire in three days. Check whether there's an automatic update mechanism in place with your hoster, or whether you have to do anything manually to renew it.)

Comment: Could you explain what a certificate chain is? My webhost service (BlueHost) automatically requests updates I believe. Is there something I need to do after that? I see a screen in the manager that says "Certificate Signing Requests." Is that something I need to do when my SSL is renewed?

Comment: _"Could you explain what a certificate chain is?"_ - your Google broken ...? https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-certificate-chain/ If installing the certificate is handled via the configuration panel, then check the documentation for that. If it doesn't mention the issue, contact the hosting provider.

Comment: No my google machine is working. I should have just looked that up myself. Thank you for the link though. I guess I am just feeling overwhelmed with figuring out this SSL thing and subconsciously it feels better to have someone who obviously knows more than me provide the info. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I updated the SSL. I have tried to figure out this issue that facebook lists. There are two critical errors now:

1. Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.
2. The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

same URL: https://www.erichalpenny.com/story-steinbeck-eden/

When I look at the source for the page, the og objects are all listed. When I look at older pages, there are more og objects listed than on this one, but they are still not displayed.

Comment: Whatever you have updated regarding SSL, has not fixed the issue - see link to SSL check tool above.. The second error is likely to go away, after you fixe the first one.

Comment: Honestly, I can't understand anything about how to fix the problem. I just don't understand what it is telling me to do to fix this intermediate chain certificate.

Comment: Honestly, please go check with your hoster for support ...

Comment: I did that today. I was on with them for 2 hours and they couldn't help. I do appreciate your time. thanks.

Comment: What kind of incompetent hoster is that? Anyway, once you figured out which issuer certificates you need for the complete chain (please tell me whoever issued that certificate to you is able to provide at least that info properly), it is usually just a matter of copy&pasting your certificate and the additional ones together in a text file, and then uploading that in cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the SSL, then see if the other errors are still there.
It appears you haven't installed the chain certificates, and I believe that's why facebook doesn't accept it (and acts as if there was no content because the content wasn't secure).

Your certificate is from Comodo (issued by UbiquiTLS), look at [their installation instructions](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/comodo/Knowledgebase/List/Index/37) for the webserver you're using.

If you don't have access to the server itself, what administration panel are you using?

Also note that your certificate runs out in three days, you might want to start anew. If you just need basic SSL, I usually use Cloudflare's free plan and let them worry about the technical details.

Comment: Thank you, I'm working on the UbiquiTLS instructions. I use cPanel through BlueHost, is that your question? It is a free SSL certificate.

Comment: Yeah, cPanel should work just fine. Merge the Certificate with the additional Chain Certificates. Also check if UbiquiTLS has special instructions on their site.